# Bootstrap Modal - Submit not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap for building a new website and I have a registration form inside a modal! Here is the code of my modal/registration form:

```
<!-- BEGIN # MODAL REGISTRATION -->
<div class="modal fade" id="registration-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">

        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" align="center">
                    <div class="icon-wrapper"> <i class="fa fa-anchor fa-4x"></i> </div>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <div class="icon-wrapper"> <i class="fa  fa-close"></i> </div>
                    </button><br>
                </div>

                <!-- Begin # DIV Form -->
                <div id="div-forms">

                    <!-- Begin # Registration Form -->
                    <form method="post" action="register.php" id="registration-form" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">

                        <p>Willkommen zur Registrierung</p><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Schule:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <select class="form-control" name="schule" id="schule" data-conditional="schule">
                            <option value="no_selected" checked>Bitte auswählen</option>
                            <option value="AHS Waldschule 1">AHS Waldschule 1</option>
                            <option value="AHS Waldschule 2">AHS Waldschule 2</option>
                            <option value="AHS Waldschule 3">AHS Waldschule 3</option>
                        </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="hide conditional-logic" data-condition="schule" data-match="AHS Waldschule 1">
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputKlasse" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Klasse:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <select class="form-control" name="klasse">
                                <option>1A</option>
                                <option>1B</option>
                                <option>1C</option>
                                <option>1D</option>
                                <option>2A</option>
                                <option>2B</option>
                                <option>2C</option>
                                <option>2D</option>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="hide conditional-logic" data-condition="schule" data-match="AHS Waldschule 2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputKlasse" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Klasse:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <select class="form-control" name="klasse">
                                <option>3A</option>
                                <option>3B</option>
                                <option>3C</option>
                                <option>3D</option>
                                <option>4A</option>
                                <option>4B</option>
                                <option>4C</option>
                                <option>4D</option>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="hide conditional-logic" data-condition="schule" data-match="AHS Waldschule 3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputKlasse" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Klasse:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <select class="form-control" name="klasse">
                                <option>5A</option>
                                <option>5B</option>
                                <option>5C</option>
                                <option>5D</option>
                                <option>6A</option>
                                <option>6B</option>
                                <option>6C</option>
                                <option>6D</option>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <hr>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Anrede:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <select class="form-control" name="anrede">
                                <option>Herr</option>
                                <option>Frau</option>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputVorname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Vorname:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="vorname" placeholder="Ihr Vorname">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputNachname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nachname:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nachname" placeholder="Ihr Nachname">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputStrasse" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Strasse:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="strasse" placeholder="Ihre Adresse">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputPLZ" class="col-sm-2 control-label">PLZ:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="plz" placeholder="Ihre Postleitzahl">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputOrt" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ort:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ort" placeholder="Ihr Wohnort">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Ihre E-Mail Adresse">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputTelefon" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Telefon:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="telefon" placeholder="Ihre Telefonnummer">
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <p>Text Text Text
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block" value="Registrieren" /> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </form>

                    <!-- End # Registration Form -->

                </div>
                <!-- End # DIV Form -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END # MODAL REGISTRATION -->
```

I made form action="register.php" and my register.php looks like this:

```
    <?php
include 'inc/database.php';

// Check if form is submitted
if (isset ($_POST['submit'])) {
    $schule = mysqli_real_escape_string ($mysqli, $_POST['schule']);
    $klasse = mysqli_real_escape_string ($mysqli, $_POST['klasse']);
    $anrede = mysqli_real_escape_string ($mysqli, $_POST['anrede']);
    $vorname = mysqli_real_escape_string ($mysqli, $_POST['vorname']);
    $nachname = mysqli_real_escape_string ($mysqli, $_POST['nachname']);
    $strasse = mysqli_real_escape_string ($mysqli, $_POST['strasse']);
    $plz = mysqli_real_escape_string ($mysqli, $_POST['plz']);
    $ort = mysqli_real_escape_string ($mysqli, $_POST['ort']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string ($mysqli, $_POST['email']);
    $telefon = mysqli_real_escape_string ($mysqli, $_POST['telefon']);

    // Set Timezone
    date_default_timezone_set('Austria/Vienna');
    $time = date('h:i:s a', time());

    // Validate Input
    if (!isset ($schule) || $schule == '' || !isset($klasse) || $klasse == ''  || !isset($anrede) || $anrede == '' || !isset($vorname) || $vorname == '' || !isset($nachname) || $nachname == '' || !isset($strasse) || $strasse == '' || !isset($plz) || $plz == '' || !isset($ort) || $ort == '' || !isset($email) || $email == '' || !isset($telefon) || $telefon == '') {
        $error = "Es müssen alle Felder ausgefüllt werden!";
        header("Location: index.php?error=".urlencode($error));
        exit();
    } else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO user (schule, klasse, anrede, firstname_parent, lastname_parent, street_parent, plz_parent, city_parent, email, phonenumber_parent, time)
                    VALUES ('$schule','$klasse', '$anrede', '$vorname', '$nachname', '$strasse', '$plz', '$ort', '$email', '$telefon','$time')";

        if(!mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)) {
            die ('Error!' .mysqli_error($mysqli));
        } else {
            header("Location: admin.php");
            exit();
    }
}

}
```

My problem is that absolutley nothing happens when I click on the "Register" button. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I looked for more than 3 hours now but I am unable to find the problem :(!

I hope that someone can help me.
Thanks in advance!

Chris

Comment: well for one thing, some of your select's option do not have a value set for them. `<option>1A</option>` for example.

Comment: Run the page in Chrome and use the Developer Tools to view the console, see if there are any errors.  If not, use the Network window to see if the request going to the server looks correct.

Comment: @Fred-ii- you don't have to specify a `value` attribute, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option - _"If this attribute is omitted, the value is taken from the text content of the option element"_

Comment: Are you using any other javascript / jquery code? If yes please add it too, so we can have a look.

Comment: Attribute name conflict `name="klasse"` why 3 of the same name?

Comment: @duncan Fair enough. ^ See comment above.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Are you trying to submit this without a page redirect (i.e., to register.php)? If so, you should consider submitting with AJAX and you can initiate the call using `.click`

Answer (score 0):

In the form group section just before the submit button section you haven't closed your 'p' tag. I think this may be stopping the submit button from working?

```
<div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
           <p>Text Text Text
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to close the `<p>` tag, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p - _"The end tag may be omitted if ... there is no more content in the parent element"_